# how to manage wifi driver in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers

My lenovo x201 has a constant problem of disconnecting after a short period of time. I have reason to believe that this is because it switches to power off to save energy.
How do I manage wifi driver in Ubuntu. I'm new to it but in windows I would fix this by,
control panel -> system properties -> device manager -> under wireless card select property.

-untick windows device swithoff for power saving
-Power output to maximum
-Roaming aggressiveness to low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing, is probably the power management setting kicking in.

Try openening a terminal and running the command `iwconfig wlan0`. That will tell you if Power Management is turned on or off.

To permenantly turn off power management, follow the guide [here](http://itechscotland.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/how-to-permanently-turn-off-wi-fi-power-management-in-ubuntu/).

Good luck.

Comment: `ifconfig` only shows ethernet-layer properties of an interface, maybe you meant `iwconfig`?

Comment: @mniip Yeah, I meant iwconfig. editing the post now. :)